# Unable to get textarea from PHP contact form

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I've got a simple contact form in PHP that is to send a form input to the email address. However, the textarea isn't included. The name and e-mail is being sent, but the textarea is blank.

My form:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" id="form" role="form" class="form contact-form">                               
    <!-- Form Heading -->
    <h3 class="small-section-heading align-center">I&#39;m always open to talk</h3>

    <!-- Name -->
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" pattern=".{2,100}" required>
    </div>

    <!-- Email -->
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="Email" pattern=".{5,100}" required>
    </div>

    <!-- Message -->
    <div class="form-group">
         <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- Send Button -->                                 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-spacia btn-medium btn-full">
          Send
    </button>
</form>
```

My PHP Contact form:

```
<?php    
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $message=$_POST['message'];
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $subject="Message sent using your contact form"; 

    mail("email@example.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
?>

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. 
<?php   
     }   
?>
```

Comment: please reformat your question's code and not using `>` but to highlight the code you want indented and hit the CTRL-K or "code" `{}`. Edit: thanks.

Comment: I can not read it at all ... Prove the style !

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited it

Comment: If that's your full php, there's an error in there `<?php   
     }   
?>` there is not opening brace for it. If not, then simply get rid of that piece.

Comment: are you using JS with this also? the id's suggests it

Comment: Error reporting had it been used http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have thrown you an `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'` error message, just so you know. Everything can be found in the duplicate question this was closed with.

Answer (score 0):

After testing your code, it seems you have a syntax error as your have a closing curly brace without an opening one. Once I removed this, it seemed to pick it up fine. So just remove the:

```
<?php
    }
?>
```

This is why it's important, in this case, to leave `error_reporting` on while you're developing so you have an insight into why your script isn't working.